# How to deploy the openAPI via the Azure CLI on linux machine?

Tags: openapi, azure-cli

I am using linux machine and installed the Azure CLI. I can create the Resource group and create the deployment via the CLI but not found How to deploy the openAPI via the Azure CLI on linux machine ? Is there a way to use Azure CLI to deploy the openAPI ?

Comment: OpenAPI is a specification. There are many different implementations of APIs and they will have totally different deployment approaches. Please specify what your API is written in for this question to be answerable.

Comment: @TomW I am talking about the Microsoft Azure API Management service. I have created the API manually via the Azure portal but need to achieve via the Azure CLI. Can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure CLI [does not list any support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim) for deploying APIs as per its documentation, but the [Azure Powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/scripts/powershell-import-api-and-add-to-product) does. You can deploy an API using an OpenAPI spec - which it calls a Swagger document - using the following command:

`Import-AzApiManagementApi -Context $context -SpecificationUrl $swaggerUrl -SpecificationFormat Swagger -Path $apiPath`